# how to allocate more storage for home directory?

Tags: partition

After checking the file systems, I noticed there is a usage of 60% for `/home`. and /home only has a very limited of 23GB storage space. On the normal windows I used to own I had more than 800GB of free storage, is there way I can allocate that storage to `/home`?

`df` result:
[image]

`lsblk`:
[image]

Comment: How is your storage currently organized? Post the output of `df` and `lsblk`.

Comment: @Gilles sir, I added the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [mkdrive2's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/261686/edit) you may want to consider just creating a new partition and using that for large data.

Resizing partitions can be tricky, especially if the `/home` partition is in physically located between other partitions. It always carries a risk that something might go wrong, so be sure to make a backup before you change partitions with a GParted live distro or similar.